# Error setting up a form to uplaod PDFs

Tags: php, pdf, post, file-upload

I'm setting up a form to upload PDFs and having trouble figuring out the root of my problem.

I have a form on one page.

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="step3.php" method="post">
          <label>Select Any PDF's For This Product <br /><span style="font-size:12px; margin-left: 4px;">(Must be pdf format. Max file size 60MB)</span></label><br /><br />
          <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="60000" />
          <input name="uploadedpdf1" type="file" /><br />
          <input name="uploadedpdf2" type="file" /><br />
          <input name="uploadedpdf3" type="file" /><br />
          <input name="uploadedpdf4" type="file" /><br />
          <input name="uploadedpdf5" type="file" /><br /><br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next Step" />
        </form>
```

Then on the next page I'm using a long PHP script to upload and validate the files. My problem starts at the beggening of the script so I will post a very simplified version.

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; ++$i) {    
$file = "uploadedpdf{$i}";

if($_FILES[$file]["name"]!="") {

$fileName = $_FILES[$file]["name"]; 
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES[$file]["tmp_name"]; 
$fileType = $_FILES[$file]["type"]; 
$fileSize = $_FILES[$file]["size"]; 
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES[$file]["error"]; 
}}
```

At this point I'm just getting information about the uploaded file to see if it can be uploaded.

I get back no value for $_FILES[$file]["tmp_name"] or $_FILES[$file]["type"].

$_FILES[$file]["size"] = 0

$_FILES[$file]["error"] = 2

But $_FILES[$file]["name"] works fine.

Why doesn't my file have a size and how can I go about debugging the 2 errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before accessing the information in `$_FILES`, you should [check the `error` entry](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php). In your case, an error of 2 means the size of the uploaded file is greater than the numeric value of the POST field `MAX_FILE_SIZE`, typically set with a hidden input field. Check that this input field has the correct `value`, or remove it.

Comment: I see my form has a MAX_FILE_SIZE of value="60000" it was suppost to handle 60MB but it must be way off. Do you know what value I would need for 60MB?

Answer (score 2):

The file is too big. According to the error number (you can see a list on the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)):

> UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE
>
> ```
> Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive
> ```
>
> that was specified in the HTML form.

Yours is

```
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="60000" />
```

Edit after comment:

the size is specified in bytes, so 60 MB = 61,440,000. Also, be careful to have the php INI settings that allows such a size (directive *upload_max_filesize*), and that it doesn't exceed your time limit.